# Communication with relational databases (MySQL) on NodeJs. Best practices

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, design-patterns

I am working on REST API, based on NodeJs.

My app get data from MySQL and return to clients. I try to organize my code which works with MySQL.

Can I use repository + unit of work patterns?

Is "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" of Martin Fowler still actual for NodeJs development? (can I read this book and use all of them, in depends of situations of course?).

Is this project a good example of how I should do? https://github.com/ErickWendel/NodeJSWithTypescript

Or maybe exists another patterns for NodeJs development? Could you recommend good sources of information?